# How can I create new branch before last 3 commit and move last 3 commit into new branch ?(I push my all commit in gitlab)

Tags: git, gitlab

How can I create a new branch before last 3 commits and move last 3 commits into the new branch?
From :

```
a -> b ->c -> d-> e -> f (master)
```

To:

```
a-> b->c(master)
        \
         d-> e-> -> f(new_branch)
```

Comment: This question has been answered many times. I've noted one of the mroe highly voted discussions.  Since you point out that you've pushed these commits, I would highlight that you would be rewriting the history of `master`, and need to understand the costs of doing that.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger OK I get the downvote now. You're right, I've answered too hastily.

Answer (score 2):

**If you're the sole owner of the repo, without the need to preserve a shared history with coworkers :**

From your `master` branch currently pointing at `f` :

```
# create your new branch
git branch new_branch

# reset master where it should
git reset --hard c

# then push the rewritten version of master to gitlab (assuming "origin" here)
git push -f origin master
```

**If, in the other hand, you're sharing this repo, breaking `master`'s history is probably to be avoided (discuss it with your team).**